# Use open ended input field & use it to email one of three different email addresses based on input such as, zip code or state with PHP?

Tags: php, email

I have a website that has a request a quote in a sidebar. They now want to sort the requests by input by state but the field is open. It accepts anything but blank currently. First, can anyone recommend a good place to gather all the zip codes of a state? I currently see there are 1365 zip codes in GA alone is there some API I can call or download? We are not even talking about cities. Is it even possible to do Zip, Cities and State? Would is just be recommended to force them to pick a state in a drop-down in addition to the input fields already in the sidebar?

```
$moving_from = strtolower($moving_from);
if($moving_from === 'georgia' || $moving_from === 'ga') {
    $emailTo = 'georgia@example.com';
}

<div class="main-input">
<label>Moving From:</label>
<input name="moving_from" type="text" value="<?php echo $moving_from; ?>" class=""/>
</div>

if(!isset($hasError)) {

    $subject = 'Submitted message from '.$f_name;
    $email2name = 'Website Lead';

    $body  = '<table><tbody>';
    $body .= '<tr><td>Name:</td><td>'.$f_name.'</td></tr>';
    $body .= '<tr><td>Date Of Move:</td><td>'.$date_of_move.'</td></tr>';
    $body .= '<tr><td>Moving From:</td><td>'.$moving_from.'</td></tr>';
    $body .= '<tr><td>Moving To:</td><td>'.$moving_to.'</td></tr>';
    $body .= '<tr><td>Email:</td><td>'.$email.'</td></tr>';
    $body .= '<tr><td>Phone Number:</td><td>'.$phone.'</td></tr>';
    $body .= '<tr><td>Size Of Move:</td><td>'.$size_of_move.'</td></tr>';
    $body .= '<tr><td>Comments:</td><td>'.$comments.'</td></tr>';
    $body .= '</tbody></table>';

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: '.$email2name.' <'.$email2.'>' . "\r\n";

    mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);

    $emailSent = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The 2 digit prefix of a zip code (almost) uniquely define the state. The first 3 digits will uniquely define the state. USPS has a full list of the 3-digit prefixes here: http://pe.usps.com/text/LabelingLists/L002.htm. I'm sure there are probably CSV/Excel files you can donwload somewhere with this information.

However, a better approach might be to use USPS's APIs for address and zip code validation. USPS has the [WebTools API](https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/welcome.htm). They're a little annoying to work with, but are free and aren't really that bad. There's a PHP library you can use which removes most of the complexity: https://github.com/VinceG/USPS-php-api. Check out the ["City State Lookup"](https://github.com/VinceG/USPS-php-api/blob/master/demos/citystatelookup.php) example--it's very similar to what you want to do.

```
$verify->addZipCode('91730');

print_r($verify->lookup());
$response = $verify->getArrayResponse();
$validated_state = $response['State'];
print_r($response);
echo $validated_state;
```

Other options are http://zipcodedistanceapi.redline13.com/ and http://smartystreets.com/products/liveaddress-api.

Comment: hmm. I would have to use substr to cut off the last two digits if the person enters a zip? I seems that "City State Lookup" would just look up a zip code. Does it do anything else?

Comment: The "City State" lookup maps a zipcode to the city and state it's associated with. You would replace `'91730'` in the example with the HTTP GET/POST parameter the user supplied.